# Firebase Showing Permission Denied On Android When Trying to Logout

Tags: java, android, firebase

i am receiving this error toasts "permission denied", "user does not have permission to perform this operation" in my android app, when ever i clicked the logout button. It does not look like an exception though, because my am does not crash, but the error keeps popping up incessantly. Is there any thing i can do to avoid this. Thanks.

I think it is due to the database event listeners, which was not removed after clicking the logout button, is there a way i can remove all the database event listeners after logging out.

Below is my logout code.

````
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.sign_out:
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return  false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mUserRef.removeEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }```

 "rules": {
    ".read":"auth != null",
    ".write":"auth != null"
  }
````

Comment: Is your question why you are getting the error or how you can remove the listeners?

Comment: why am i getting the error and how i can solve it?

Comment: In that case you will need to ad the actual error message to your question. And while you are doing that you might want to capitalize the i's :)

Comment: the error message i am getting is: "permission denied", "user does not have permission to perform this operation".